# PostGIS built for PostgreSQL 13.0 cannot be loaded in PostgreSQL 14.2

Tags: django, postgresql, archlinux

I am running arch Linux, I installed postgresql and postgis to work with it in my Django project, but whenever i try to migrate my models i get this error

```
PostGIS built for PostgreSQL 13.0 cannot be loaded in PostgreSQL 14.2
```

can anyone tell me what's the problem here please

Comment: The error message is clear, isn't it? Build PostGIS with PostgreSQL v14.

Comment: i tried to add the extension but it didn't work, i installed the last version of postgresql and postgis

Comment: @th3plus How did you install the last version of each?  Evidently, it did not install them properly.

Comment: @laurenzAlbe sudo pacman -S postgresql and sudo pacman -S postgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer if anyone having the same problem like me , dowload the pkgbuild and postgis.changelog and build postgis using makepkg -si